# Windows 10 goes to sleep ignoring the settings

Tags: windows-10, sleep

My Lenovo laptop's settings:

- is plugged in
- no screensaver
- "never" go to sleep/hybernate set to all settings in advanced power options

When music is playing or watching video everything works fine.
But when nothing is happening pc goes to sleep after ~1 min.
Not sure, but it doesn't happen right after restart, only after I begin working.
Here is the system log for sleep event:

> - System
>
>   - Provider
>
>   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power     [ Guid] 
>     {331C3B3A-2005-44C2-AC5E-77220C37D6B4} 
>      EventID 42 
>      Version 2 
>      Level 4 
>      Task 64 
>      Opcode 0 
>      Keywords 0x8000000000000004
>
>   - TimeCreated
>
>   [ SystemTime]  2015-10-13T20:02:20.555603100Z 
>      EventRecordID 1736 
>      Correlation
>
>   - Execution
>
>   [ ProcessID]  4     [ ThreadID]  4412 
>      Channel System 
>      Computer pcname 
>      Security
> - EventData
>
>   TargetState 4    EffectiveState 4    Reason 7    Flags 0

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you on a metered connection?

Comment: Try this link (and if it works, write an answer here) : https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-windows-10-sleep-mode/

Answer (score 10):

It is the *System unattended sleep timeout* setting.

By default it is set to 120 seconds and is hidden.

Setting the registry data *Attributes* under key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0` to value 2 (or 0) makes the option appear in the advanced power settings, under *Sleep* and can be set to something normal.

Source: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/72133-add-system-unattended-sleep-timeout-power-options-windows-10-a.html

Comment: It's the "Attributes" key under that location that should be set to 2.